# epstopdf creates blank PDF files

Tags: epstopdf

I have an issue with `epstopdf.exe` and that leads to inability to use .eps files for creating pdf documents. Here is the example of console output when I try to transform a sample eps file manually using epstopdf:

```
c:\>epstopdf --verbose r_t_a.eps
Making c:\r_t_a.pdf from c:\r_t_a.eps...
epstopdf: Invalid argument

c:\>Error: /ioerror in --run--
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   (/Uni)
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval-
-   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   fa
lse   1   %stopped_push   1926   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1169/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

I also get this "epstopdf: Invalid argument" for every .eps image I try to use in my .tex document. Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: It is possible to see the EPS?

Comment: Does it work if you move the eps to some folder instead of trying to compile in C:\?

Comment: @daleif I think it doesn't matter because on my second PC all my eps files (including "r_t_a.eps") transform with 'epstopdf'. And on this PC epstopdf always returns "Invalid argument" message.

Comment: Then check if the versions are the same